# Error: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown[7]

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I keep getting the `FileNotFoundException`, even though I´m throwing it.

Here´s the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    
public class kt_6_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("magicSquare.txt");
        fileRead(file);
    }
    static void fileRead (File dummyFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dummyFile);
        String[] squareLines = new String[3];
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
            squareLines[a] = scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(squareLines[2]);
    }
}
```

edit: the error message is:

```
kt_6_2.java:7: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught
 or declared to be thrown
                fileRead(file);
                        ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your main method is calling your `fileRead()` method. And instead of handling exception your fileRead() method has decided to throw the Exception.

So in exception scenario, once its thrown from `fileRead()` method it should be caught in your `main()` method. However, your main() can further throw this exception.

you need to write as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
 ....
```

or if you want to handle the exception, you should write as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("magicSquare.txt");
     try{
        fileRead(file);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           //exception handling code
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the "throws FileNotFoundException" to the main() method, but now I have two of them, one in main() and one in the fileRead method. Is that a mistake or is it correct?

Comment: Syntactically, its correct. But in general you should catch your compile-time (checked) exceptions and do appropriate processing/handling instead of blindly throwing it.

Answer (score 1):

> must be caught or declared to be thrown

What exactly do you not understand here?
You use a method `fileRead` that can throw `FileNotFoundException`, hence you must either catch it, or hand it upwards, so your `main` method would need a throws clause.

But the latter choice is, of course, a bad one. So simply wrap that `readFile` invokation in a try/catch block.